# Swing: Graphing availability over time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graph

I'm not a UI person, so I'm hoping to get some suggestions for how to draw this in Swing. I want to end up with something like the figure below.
[image]

It's showing availability over time (time axis not shown in image, but it'd be at the bottom or top). The vertical bar represents the current time.  I looked at libraries like JFreeChart, but I don't see anything that can easily be turned into this, or did I miss something? It's easy enough to draw something like this manually by overriding paint() in a JPanel or something, but I don't want to have to manually handle the collapsing/expanding logic over elements on the left. My next thought was maybe a JTree with custom cells where I could draw the availability bars. This way I won't have to deal with the collapse/expand logic.

Any suggestions? Is there a charting/graphing library I could use? Should I do it from scratch? Extend some existing Swing component?

Thanks

Comment: What's the part that JFreeChart doesn't work well with?

Comment: This graphic doesn't look that hard/complex, why not to draw it directly on a JPanel?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I meant it doesn't look like there are any charts that do what I want out of the box. E.g., maybe I could modify a simple line chart to do different color line segments to get the red/green lines, but how would I do the expanding/collapsing of labels on the y-axis?

Comment: @AbelMorelos I could, was just wondering if there was a better way to save some time.

Comment: I suppose you could use a JTree and have the graphs displayed using a renderer, but I've never done this myself before.

Comment: Look into using a [TreeCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html) such as a [DefaultTreeCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) if you want to go this route.

Comment: Would a [Gantt chart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GanttRenderer.html) be suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) can do everything except the outline, for which I'd use [`outline`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) and a suitable table cell renderer.

Comment: Or a `JXTreeTable` from the SwingX project

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is a "Gantt chart". JFreeChart does have a chart for that, but it's not interactive. There are some free Java library (e-gantt is one), but not in combination with a tree table (as far as I know).

So if that is required, you could build something of a tree table as suggested in the other answers or go with a commercial library (JGantt, Jide Gantt (disclaimer I worked on that one ;))